# Do Parents have ownership of their sons?

Tags: children, parents, family

Do Father and mother have absolute ownership over their sons ? Is it dharma of son to anything which his parents commands ?

PS - I am asking only for a son as a daughter after marriage no longer remains with her parents

Comment: Check out [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16256/are-hindu-children-meant-to-serve-their-parents-forever-whether-they-like-them-o) answer.